# What powers search on golang.org?

Tags: go, search

golang.org let’s you search all stdlib go source code.

For example, see https://golang.org/search?q=hello

Where is the code that serves these search queries? If the code is not public, does it use a publicly available or at least publicly documented search engine?

**I am not asking about [godoc.org search](https://godoc.org/?q=hello) which appears to be served from [appengine search](https://github.com/golang/gddo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=appengine%20search&type=). godoc.org only indexes the name of the repo - not its content - whereas golang.org indexes all files in the go core libraries and runtime.**

Comment: https://github.com/golang/tools/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=HandleSearch&type= although the package is called godoc, this ought to be the source you want. (take a look at the templates in the /static folder of the package).

Comment: The question is cross posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/kz_jsaepOlg